# From where @RenderBody() layout is calling in partial _Root.Head.cshtml in nopcommerce 4.00

Tags: model-view-controller, nopcommerce-4.0

In nopcommerce, when we start the project at that time in `_ColumnOne` partial view page `RenderBody()` layout is calling by `_Root` partial view page. After in `_Root` partial view page `RenderBody()` layout is calling by `_Root.Head` partial view page. Now, my question is that in `_Root.Head` where `@RenderBody` layout is been called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow of nopcommerce flow of top, middle and footer layout of the website

_ViewStart => _Column1 => _Root => _Root.Head

```
In _ViewStart.cshtml partial page shows the path of _Column1.cshtml.

In _Column1.cshtml partial display the design between **main_column_before** and **main_column_after** and goes path to _Root.cshtml.

In _Root.cshtml shows the **top** and **footer** design of the website and forward to _Root.Head.cshtml.

In _Root.Head.cshtml shows the **middle layout** of the website.
```